# How do I make a flattened sphere shape?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I'm trying to make sort of a flat spherical shape. It is the shape of an M&M. I have looked all over the internet but have not found anything.

Comment: Do you mean *flattened* shape ? Probably you should scale your sphere by one axis (the very basic flattening)

Comment: read https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/scale.html?highlight=scale

Comment: To familiarize yourself with blender you can start here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Answer (score 6):

Use a sphere and scale it on the Z axis.

<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>

[image]

Else you can use the scale manipulator and scale on a single axis:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Add a sphere to the scene via <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Mesh > Sphere*.
2. Hit <kbd>S</kbd> to scale and then <kbd>Y</kbd> immediately to scale along the Y-Axis only
3. Then drag the mouse in the right direction to adjust the flattening

Comment: if you're interested in the key markup, here is the meta: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/524/what-case-should-letters-inside-kbd-tags-be

Comment: @poor Thank you, I was wondering how to do that.